# Vim copy and paste

Tags: vim, replace, copy-paste

My previous question seems to be a bit ambiguous, I will rephrase it:

I have a file like this:

```
copythis abc
replacethis1 xyz
qwerty replacethis2
hasfshd replacethis3 fslfs
And so on...
```

**NOTE:** replacethis1, replacethis2, replacethis3, ... could be any words

How do I replace "replacethis1","replacethis2","replacethis3",.. word by "copythis" word by using minimum vim commands.

One way I can do is by these steps:

1. delete "replacethis1","replacethis2","replacethis3",.. by using 'dw'
2. copy "copythis" using 'yw'
3. move cursor to where "replacethis1" was and do 'p'; move cursor to where "replacethis2" was and do 'p' and so on...

Is there a better way to do this in VIM (using less number of vim commands)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you changed your question, I'd do it this way:

Move to the first "replacethis1" and type cw (change word), then type "copythis" manually.

Move to the next "replacethis", hit . (repeat last operation)

Move to the next "replacethis", hit .,

and so on, and so on.

If "copythis" is a small word, I think this is the best solution.

Comment: depending on how you move to the different to-be-replaced words, it might be better to use ciw (or caw) instead of cw. For cw to work you need to be at the beginning of replacethis.

Answer (score 4):

The digit needs to be included, and there could be more than one instance per line:

```
:%s/replacethis\d/copythis/g
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that "replacethis[1-3]" can be arbitrary unrelated words, the quickest/simplest way to do this globally would be:

```
:%s/replacethis1\|replacethis2\|replacethis3/copythis/g
```

(Note that you need to use \| to get the pipes to function as "or".  Otherwise, vim will look for the literal | character.)

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this for a long time too, I think I just worked out the cleanest way:

Use whichever command is cleanest to put copythis into register r:

```
/copythis
"rye
```

Then go to the replacement and replace it with the contents of r:

```
/replacethis
cw<CTRL-R>r<ESC>
```

Then you can just `n.n.n.n.n.n.n.` for the rest of them, or if they're wildly different just go to the beginning of each and hit `.`

The key is replacing and pasting in one step so you can use `.` later.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/copythis/replacethis/g
```

To replace all occurrences of copythis with replacethis. Or you can specify a range of line numbers like:

```
:8,10 s/copythis/replacethis/g
```

Note, the /g on the end will tell it to replace all occurrences. If you leave that off it will just do the first one.

Comment: Please see my rephrased question

Comment: You got the two terms reversed.

Answer (score 1):

1. create this mapping:

   :map z cwcopythis^[

   ( ^[ is the escape character, you can type it in vim using Ctrl+V Ctrl+[ )
2. go to each word you want to replace and press z

Comment: It will work, it's the same suggestion as mine but it creates a custom binding instead of using the built-in dot command.  It's probably better to use this if you're not replacing all of the words at once.

Comment: I'd used dw initially but realized the error as soon as I hit post, so I edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried string replacement?

```
%s/replacethis/copythis
```

A host of other parameters are possible to fine-tune the replacement. Dive into the Vim help for more details. Some more examples [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace).

Answer (score 0):

if u need to do essentially the same action multiple times - swap 1st word of one line with second word of the next line, I say you could record a macro and call it whenever you need to

Comment: Please see my rephrased question

Answer (score 0):

You can remap e.g. the `m` key in normal mode to delete the word under the cursor and paste the buffer: `:nnoremap m "_diwP`.
Then you can just copy the desired word, move the cursor anywhere onto the to-be-replaced word and type `m`.

EDIT: Mapping to m is a bad idea since it is used to mark locations. But you can use e.g. `;` anyway.